# Get Folder path in Processing scripts (QGIS 3)

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, qgis-processing, qgis-3

maybe a simple question but I cannot solve it.

In a simple Processing script I have defined a parameter as `QgsProcessingParameterFolderDestination` where I want to save some files (vector or raster) that will be created by the script.

The problem is that I cannot get the path of the chosen folder.

Here a simplified version of the script that actually does not do anything, just printing in the log tab the chosen path.

I'm defining a `QgsProcessingParameterFolderDestination` and I'm trying to get the path of the chosen folder (if chosen, else Processing will take care of the temporary path) with `self.parameterAsString`. The

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from PyQt5.QtCore import QCoreApplication
from qgis.core import (QgsProcessing,
                       QgsFeatureSink,
                       QgsProcessingException,
                       QgsProcessingAlgorithm,
                       QgsProcessingParameterFeatureSource,
                       QgsProcessingParameterFolderDestination)
import processing


class ExampleProcessingAlgorithm(QgsProcessingAlgorithm):

    INPUT = 'INPUT'
    OUTPUT = 'OUTPUT'

    def tr(self, string):
        return QCoreApplication.translate('Processing', string)

    def createInstance(self):
        return ExampleProcessingAlgorithm()

    def name(self):
        return 'myscript'

    def displayName(self):
        return self.tr('My Script')

    def group(self):
        return self.tr('Example scripts')

    def groupId(self):
        return 'examplescripts'

    def initAlgorithm(self, config=None):

        self.addParameter(
            QgsProcessingParameterFeatureSource(
                self.INPUT,
                self.tr('Input layer'),
                [QgsProcessing.TypeVectorAnyGeometry]
            )
        )

        self.addParameter(
            QgsProcessingParameterFolderDestination(
                self.OUTPUT,
                self.tr('Output layer')
            )
        )

    def processAlgorithm(self, parameters, context, feedback):

        source = self.parameterAsSource(
            parameters,
            self.INPUT,
            context
        )

        output = self.parameterAsString(
            parameters,
            self.OUTPUT,
            context
        )

        feedback.pushDebugInfo(output)


        return {self.OUTPUT: output}
```

**UPDATE**: fixed now: https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/commit/d157b6e66173

Comment: I don't see the problem here - in your `processingAlgorithm` method the `output` object is the path of the chosen folder, which is what you want. This works for me - if I put /foo/bar in the output folder choice box, I see that sent to the output by `feedback.pushDebugInfo`...

Comment: If this really isn't working for you, could you give us the precise version number of QGIS? I'm using 3.0.3

Comment: that's weird. So for you the script of above prints your chosen path to in the Log tab? In my case, even if I add `createOutput=True` the output is still `/tmp/processing_320e1069a41a40f2924ec2569a6d67f5/efb011cb999d4ede8c3cb4c70955b6b7/OUTPUT
`

Comment: Wait a second.. **if** I write the path **manually** it works, if I choose the path with the button I have to type a space or something in the string. It seems that it is not able to recognize the path if taken from somewhere, only if I type something in the box.

Comment: Uh sorry yes. I'm on a Linux Debian Sid machine with QGIS master compiled from source.

Comment: Your test script works for me with QGIS 3.0.3 on Ubuntu 18.04 with Qt 5.10 and CentOS 6 with Qt 5.6. Tested using the selection dialog as well as typing in the path.

Comment: Ok it was a small bug. Fixed now for master: https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/commit/d157b6e66173 QGIS devs rock!